# Error Message of " throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'Function', value); "

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I was working on my discord.js v13, but I got this error message on my console:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

This is the code of `messageCrete.js`:

```
const { messageEmbed, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const client = require('..');
const config = require('../config.json');
const prefix = config.prefix;

//messageCreate events
client.on("messageCreate"), async (message) => {
    if(!message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(cmd.length === 0 ) return;
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if(!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    command.run(client, message, args);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `client.on("messageCreate"), async (message) => {` should be `client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {` and the last `}` should be `})`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
// code here
});
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. You should [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) instead once you earn enough reputation and/or leave a comment. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons.